# How do I use re.search on an entire file, rather than line by line?

Tags: python, file, python-re

I am trying to find a pattern in a file, however the pattern I would like to match spans across multiple lines in the file.

pattern = r"stringofcharacters"

for line in file:
match = re.search(pattern,line)

unfortunately, this only works on one line at a time, whereas I need to find a pattern that goes across several lines.

Comment: Read the entire file into a single string and then use `re.search`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use -  `match = re.search(pattern,file.read())`